# Visual Studio Analyze Code Coverage throws exceptions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

Hy i wrote some tests for my Application. Now i was curious how good i covered my code so i wanted to use the Code Coverage from Visual Studio. If i run the tests normally all of them will pass. But if I run them with the Anylyzer i always geth this exception:

```
Assert.Fail failed. The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' was not found.    at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at MyTestlass.RunApplicationTest(CrossAppDomainDelegate test)
```

I looked at the test settings but i could not find something.

All of my tests share the same base test class since i am setting up in tthere the application. in ther i have a methode for setting up the application:

```
protected static void RunApplicationTest(CrossAppDomainDelegate test) {
...
}
```

Here i am confused why the exception tells me it needs a constructor for the deserialization.

Comment: Showing the code for test which fails would be a good thing

Comment: Does the problematic code have a type that implements ISerialized to implement a serialization constructor?